# Excel VBA: Using Evaluate Match with "OR"

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code already set up to return the row number of a row that contains "Car" in column A, "Fiat" in column B, and "Yellow" in column G.

```
Set ws1 = Sheets("Database")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Insert")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet1")


1_cell = "Car"
2_cell = "Fiat"
3_cell = "Yellow"

row_num2 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A:A=""" & 1_cell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!B:B=""" & 2_cell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!G:G=""" & 3_cell & """),0)")
```

But I'm trying to figure out how I can make it so it looks for a row that contains "Car", "Fiat" and in column G it either has "Yellow" OR "Green".

I don't want it to only produce matches that contain "Yellow", I want it to be able to match if it has "Green" instead in the same column.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Linke something like a Googledocs spreadsheet so it's easy for someone o correct. That way you'll likely get an answer quicker.

Comment: I'm not allowed to share the spreadsheet, so I wrote a conceptual version of it with my post (changed the variable names, sheet names etc.). So what I have embedded will have to suffice as an example of what I'm working with unfortunately

Comment: So do something conceptually in Googledocs.

Comment: First of all: you MUST NOT start the name of your variables with a number: cell_1 is ok, 1_cell is a nogo. I am not sure if VBA lets you do it, but just don't do it.

Comment: In my actual spreadsheet the names of the variables are different, I just edited them on StackOverflow to mask the names. Good to know anyway though, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Untested**. But should do the job assuming your code was working

```
1_cell = "Car"
2_cell = "Fiat"
3_cell = "Yellow"
4_cell = "Green"

row_num_1 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A:A=""" & 1_cell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!B:B=""" & 2_cell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!G:G=""" & 3_cell & """),0)")
row_num_2 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A:A=""" & 1_cell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!B:B=""" & 2_cell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!G:G=""" & 4_cell & """),0)")

row_num2 = WorksheetFunction.Min(row_num_1, row_num_2)
```

Comment: How does .Min work in this context? Would the match produce the FIRST row that had either Yellow or Green. So if row 2 had Yellow and row 5 had Green it would return row 2 as it's the first occurrence?

Comment: Yes .. So basically you will get 2 rows .. Maybe row 2 with Yellow, and row 5 with Green. So min will give you 2, which should be the result of a Match function with OR.

Comment: I'm getting "The item with the specified name wasn't found"

Comment: Ah scratch that, it was a mistake on my end. Seems to work! Thanks for your help